# Google Apps Script PropertiesService Unexpected Token in Obj Literal

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using Google Apps PropertyService to store some settings variables. When I use the setProperties() function and give it an object (just like they do in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperties(Object))) and then try to get a property and parse it I am getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token in Object Literal`.

The PropertiesService is emptied before I run this code. As far as I understand I am getting a string back that I should be able to parse into an object.

```
function setDefaults(){
  var def = {
    config: {
      isSetup: false
    },
    test: {
      page: true
    }
}

var docServ = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
docServ.setProperties(def, true);

log(typeof docServ.getProperty("config")); //string
log(docServ.getProperty("config")); //{isSetup=false}
log(JSON.parse(docSer.getProperty("config"))); //SyntaxError
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the issue has something to do with multiple nested objects. Apparently, the JSON parser can only go down one level.

Calling JSON.stringify() on each of the nested objects solved the problem for me:

```
 var def = {config: {isSetup: false}, test: {page: true}};

  for (var prop in def) {

    def[prop] = JSON.stringify(def[prop]);

  }

var docServ = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
docServ.setProperties(def, true);

var config  = JSON.parse(docServ.getProperty("config"));

Logger.log(config.isSetup); //logs 'false'
```

Comment: Haha. Thank you so much! To be honest I had been working on this for at least 3 hours! I guess I can chalk it up to inexperience with Javascript? Bleh... Thanks again!!

Comment: setProperties() takes an object so shouldn't it work without stringify-ing the inner properties?

Comment: @ChrisWood Agreed - it should. For some reason, though, it works only if the object doesn’t contain any properties that themselves are objects.